# What does a @() in objective-c means?

Tags: objective-c

I've seen `@(NO)` in objective-c code, I guess it's a kind of syntactic sugar, but what does it actually mean?

Comment: It's mean, that peoples, who write `@(NO)` don't know that they can write just `@NO`.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @Cy-4AH Seems the two are only identical here, for the one without a parentheses always creates an NSNumber object but the @() can judge dynamically.

Comment: @Caesar no, 1. @ without parentheses can result in other kinds of literals as well (`@""`: strings, `@[]`: arrays, `@{}`: dictionaries), and `@()` doesn't work "dynamically", it needs to know the type at compilation time.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes you're right, but it's just a matter of classification for I simply set `@""`,`@[]`,`@{}` as special forms. Dynamically here doesn't mean runtime-confirmation but automatically. Sorry I didn't express myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**@(expression)**

Dynamically evaluates the boxed expression and returns the appropriate object literal based on its value (i.e. NSString for const char*, NSNumber for int, etc.). This is also the designated way to use number literals with enum values.

[compiler-directives](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/)